# Time tense for the question "have you?"

Tags: questions, past-perfect

Please, I need help with this question. Should I use the participle or base form of the verb with the past participle question of:
Have you find or have you found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have/has + subject + past participle. (question)

Subject + have/has + past participle. (statement)

For example:

> **Have you found?**
>
> **You have found**.